# Custom List Tile includes unnecessary padding

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a list view which includes custom rows. Below is the source code I used to generate each List Tile. Somehow Container has unnecesary paddings.

```
return Container(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/poligon.png'),
              )
            ),
          // Line

          Transform.rotate(
              angle: 0.022218565326719023,
              child: Container(
                  width: 1,
                  height: 37.99062075760125,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: const Color(0xff33ac0c),
                          width: 2
                      )
                  )
              )
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]